# inequality: $\tan2x+\tan2y+\tan2z \geq 3\sqrt{3}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

I tried to prove a inequality in trigonometric way. After changing variables, i get this problem:

If $x+y+z=\dfrac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$ then $\tan2x+\tan2y+\tan2z \geq 3\sqrt{3}$.

I can see with the condition, $\tan2x+\tan2y+\tan2z=\tan2x\tan2y\tan2z$, but its no clue to solve.

Comment: Hint $f(x)=\tan 2x$ is cconcave upwards so use jensen's inequality

Comment: Thank you but is that any more "trigonometric" way to solve? because if using jensen's inequality, i can use it for the original problem, without to changing.

Comment: The original problem is ask to solve in trigonometric way: If $xy+yz+zx=1$ then $\dfrac{x}{1-x^2}+\dfrac{y}{1-y^2}+\dfrac{z}{1-z^2}\geq \dfrac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$.